# How to host an RSS Feed on an Ubuntu VPS

Tags: rss, itunes, pubdate

I'm trying to host an RSS feed for iTunes and I keep getting a mismatched tag error

Ubuntu // Apache

feed url is:
http://fourteenthrees.com/podcasts/feed.xml

my code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<rss version="2.0" xmlns:itunes="http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd">

    <channel>
        <title>MUSIC 4 COMMITTING CRIMES</title>
        <link>http://www.fourteenthrees.com</link>
        <language>en-us</language>
        <copyright>℗ &amp; © 2019 Fourteen Threes</copyright>
        <itunes:subtitle>Music you listen to while committing crime.</itunes:subtitle>
        <itunes:author>Fourteen Threes</itunes:author>
        <itunes:summary>The soundtrack to all your crimes</itunes:summary>
        <description>Every episode is the soundtrack to a different crime.</description>
        <itunes:owner>
            <itunes:email>editor@fourteenthrees.com</itunes:email>
        </itunes:owner>
        <itunes:image href="http://fourteenthrees.com/images/podlogo.jpg"/>
        <itunes:category text="Society &amp; Culture" />
        <itunes:category text="Arts" />
        <itunes:category text="News &amp; Politics" />
        <itunes:explicit>yes</itunes:explicit>

        <item>
            <title>00 - TEST</title>
            <itunes:subtitle>DIRTROID:the girl dies</itunes:subtitle>
            <itunes:summary><![CDATA[Dirty Harry v Metroid.]]></itunes:summary>
            <itunes:image href="http://fourteenthrees.com/images/podlogo.jpg"/>
            <enclosure length="8727310" type="audio/x-m4a" url="http://fourteenthrees.com/podcasts/FT-01.mp3”/>
             <pubDate>Thu, 12 Sep 2019 16:00:00 PDT</pubDate>
            <itunes:duration>22:04</itunes:duration>
            <itunes:explicit>yes</itunes:explicit>
        </item>

   </channel>
</rss>
```

This is the error from the Apple Recommended feed validator;

Sorry,This feed does not validate. line 29, column 13: XML parsing error: :29:13: not well-formed (invalid token)
Thu, 12 Sep 2019 16:00:00 PDT

I can't see what I did wrong, could use another set of eyes, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ububtu // Apache (should've noted that in the first question)

Log in as root

First I deleted the /var/www/html/podcasts/ dir I made to house the RSS Feed

```
cd /
sudo apt-get update -y
sudo apt-get install mysql-server -y
sudo /usr/bin/mysql_secure_installation
sudo systemctl enable apache2.service
sudo systemctl enable mysql.service

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get install php7.3
systemctl restart apache2.service
```

Dowloaded [Podcast Generator](http://www.podcastgenerator.net)

Extracted the zip file to desktop and placed the new contents into a NEW folder called /podcasts/

ssh podcast folder into /var/www/html/

```
Chmod 777 /var/www/html/
Chmod 777 /var/www/html/podcasts/
Chmod 777 var/www/html/media
chmod 777 /var/www/hmtl/podcasts/images
```

Open browser, navigate to `http://eaxample.com/podcasts/setup`

Follow onscreen GUI instructions, fill out all the categories and use the FTP look up option to recognize your ssh upload if your file is over 2 mb.

Don't be afraid to navigate with the back button in the admin area, it remembers everything if you save it.

worked like a charm